# How do i only show Records from a DB where SystemDate is less/greater than stored date?

Tags: c#, linq, ado

I am creating a WPF C# application that allows you to add, remove, and edit Car Rental Orders, i am trying to implement a feature to only select records from the database that are completed, or select records that are still active.

this is my ShowCompleted Method for excample....

```
  DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
            var query = from CarRental in this.dbContext.CarRentals where (CarRental.Starting_Date.AddDays(CarRental.Duration)) < current select CarRental;
            this.CarRentalViewSource.Source = query.ToList();
```

This is the error i get when i click that button, and i have no idea what the solution is...

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: You aren't comparing against a stored date, you are *calculating* it using a C# method, `AddDays`. This can't be translated to SQL. That's what the message says

Comment: Another problem is that by *calculating* the date, even if you did so in SQL, you prevent the server from using any indexes that cover `Starting_Date`. This will force a full table scan. Create an actual or persisted calcualted field `Ending_Date` and add it to an index.

Answer (score 0):

`EntityFramework` translates all your functions to `sql`, the error is saying that `EntityFramework` cannot translate `DateTime.AddDays` function into `sql`. You need to use `DbFunctions.AddDays` instead of `DateTime.AddDays`, so your code should look like this

```
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
var query = from CarRental in this.dbContext.CarRentals where 
            (DbFunctions.AddDays(CarRental.Starting_Date, CarRental.Duration))) < current select CarRental;
this.CarRentalViewSource.Source = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Even *that* isn't a good idea because it prevents the server from using any indexes that cover the `Startging_Date` field. This will work but result in a full table scan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, you are right. but there is no other way that I know, which will work in this case. Another solution would be to store already calculated date and query over that column, which you already mentioned in the comment above)

Comment: @Ruben, are you sure this is up to date code? it seems to generate more errors than fix them